# Initializing multi dimensional arrays in lua/torch

Tags: arrays, lua, torch

I have gone through a few tutorials about "arrays" in lua/torch and all I see is the word tensors. What exactly are they? How can i initialize a 2d "tensor"? I tried `torch.Tensor{1,2,3}` which gave me

```
1
2
3
```

and `torch.Tensor{1,2,3;4,5,6}` like in octave/MATLAB but this gave me another column vector

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

How can I get a 2d "tensor" like the following?

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Also, I'm using torch to execute my lua files. Is there no other notation for arrays other than "tensors" i.e. is there no other way we can use to represent a matrix in torch?

Comment: There are Lua's standard tables of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
torch.Tensor{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
```

Have a look at [this](http://remarkjs.com/remarkise?url=https://github.com/nicholas-leonard/slides/blob/master/nvidiagtc2016.md#10) (or [that](https://github.com/eladhoffer/DeepLearningCourse/tree/master/Tutorials)) for more details on tensors.